# columnCount must be greater than or equal to the maximum of all grid indices (and spans) defined in the LayoutParams of each child

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

**What am I doing:** Trying to change the column count of `GridLayout` using its `setColumnCount()` from the `onGlobalLayout()` of `OnGlobalLayoutListener()`

**What am I trying to achieve:** I want to change the *column count* of the `GridLayout` after determining how much screen size is left for its child elements i.e. if a screen size can hold only 5 `GridLayout's` child elements then I would set the column count to 5 so that after 5th element the 6th element will be placed in the 2nd row and so on.
**How am I trying to achieve this:** First I get the total *width* of `GridLayout` using `ViewTreeObserver`. Then after divide it by the size of a single child element and then setting this as the `setColumnCount()` value.
**Code:**

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = gridLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        gridLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        int gridLayoutWidth = Utils.pxToDp(mContext,gridLayout.getWidth()); //GridLayout width in DP
        int childElementWidth = 44; //Child element width in DP
        int columnCount = (gridLayoutWidth/childElementWidth);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(columnCount);
    }
});
```

**What am I stuck at:** `columnCount must be greater than or equal to the maximum of all grid indices (and spans) defined in the LayoutParams of each child`

Comment: tried calling gridLayout.removeAllViews() before you set the column count ?

Answer (score 0):

The column or row spec for the child views needs to be set within the new range of the GridLayout before updating it with the reduced column or row count.

I created a function in Kotlin to do that for me with a specified column count and a fixed number of child views in the layout. Sorry for not writing it in Java, but it's not all that different.

```
fun setGridColumns(gridLayout: GridLayout, columns: Int) {
    var col = 0
    var row = 0
    for (child in gridLayout.children) {
        val params = child.layoutParams as GridLayout.LayoutParams
        params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(col, 1, 1f)
        params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, 1, 1f)
        if (col + 1 == columns) {
            col = 0
            row++
        } else {
            col++
        }
    }
    gridLayout.requestLayout() // Forces maxIndex to be recalculated when columnCount is set
    gridLayout.columnCount = columns
}
```